# Update value in array by code + knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0

I have a table populating an observable array using a template, I need to update a column with a Text for every row in that table and at the same time get the model updated.

thanks!

Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/pdelacruz/aqYvW/6/

Comment: When asking for help with a specific operation like this, it is helpful to post the code you have written so far.

Comment: there you are http://jsfiddle.net/pdelacruz/aqYvW/6/

Comment: Observable arrays will only monitor changes to the array itself (e.g., adding/removing items). If you want to trigger to update on changes to the items, you need to make those properties observable.

Comment: those properties are observable already, I am using knockout mapping any suggestion how to do it??

Comment: Can you be a bit more descriptive about what you want to have happen? Do you mean you want a column on each row that is like a total? Also, your data is invalidly structured.

Comment: I want to update column GateInputs[0].AntibodyInputs[0].Intensity.DataValue set its value to "Normal" for every row in the array

Answer (score 0):

Pedro

I don't think the properties on the items in your collection are observable.
The mapping plugin doesn't do this by default.

You'll have to implement the mapping with a create callback for every item in your collection and return an object with the required observable properties